# QAF Getting "Invalid Status code=403 text=Forbidden" error on launching the chrome driver after latest chrome upgrade

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, qaf, perfecto

QAF Getting "Invalid Status code=403 text=Forbidden" error on launching the chrome driver after latest chrome upgrade

Lot of them asked to provide "--remote-allow-origins=*" as chrome option arguments.

Can some one suggest how to resolve this issue in QAF Quantum Web App automation.
or How to add **"--remote-allow-origins=*"**  to **chrome.additional.capabilities** in **application.properies** file

Local machine-windows 10.

**Error Message:**

```
java.io.IOException: Invalid Status code=403 text=Forbidden**
    at org.asynchttpclient.netty.handler.WebSocketHandler.abort(WebSocketHandler.java:92)
    at org.asynchttpclient.netty.handler.WebSocketHandler.handleRead(WebSocketHandler.java:118)
    at org.asynchttpclient.netty.handler.AsyncHttpClientHandler.channelRead(AsyncHttpClientHandler.java:78)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:327)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:314)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:435)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:279)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler.channelRead(LoggingHandler.java:280)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:722)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:658)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:584)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:496)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:995)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: did you updated the chromedriver too? because some new chrome versions require new chromedriver version to work

Comment: Yes, The recommended latest chrome driver version **"ChromeDriver 111.0.5563.64"**  only I'm using from https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads .  My Current Local chrome browser was upgraded to **"111.0.5563.111"**

Answer (score 0):

Related to your question How to add "--remote-allow-origins=*" to `chrome.additional.capabilities` you can try following:

```
{"browserName":"chrome","goog:chromeOptions":{"args":["--remote-allow-origins=*"]}}
```

To generate json for any capability/options object, you can use following snippet.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        //set required options
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
        //print it and use it as capabilities
        System.out.println(JSONUtil.toString(chromeOptions.asMap()));
}
```